# How do you create a weak reference to an object in Python?

Tags: python, weak-references

How do you create a weak reference to an object in Python?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
>>> import weakref
>>> class Object:
...     pass
...
>>> o = Object()
>>> r = weakref.ref(o)
>>> # if the reference is still active, r() will be o, otherwise None
>>> do_something_with_o(r())
```

See the [wearkref module docs](http://docs.python.org/lib/module-weakref.html) for more details.
You can also use `weakref.proxy` to create an object that proxies o. Will throw `ReferenceError` if used when the referent is no longer referenced.